# Stata: make predictions for new dataset using results of mvprobit (multivariate probit model)

Tags: stata, prediction, predict

I have estimated a multivariate probit model with four equations using the `mvprobit` command in Stata.

The four dependent variables are: does a farm adopt rainfed farming (yes/no), surface irrigation, sprinkler irrigation and/or drip irrigation?

Using the regression output, I would now like to predict the (binary) outcomes for a new dataset. To my knowlegde, the postestimation command `mvppred` cannot be used for this.

I am not sure whether there is Stata code to solve this issue. Otherwise, I assume there must be a formula to manually predict the outcome variables using the regression coefficients and values of the independent variables. But which is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post-estimation command `mvppred` can be used. Retain the estimates of the fitted model in memory; add observations to the dataset in memory with characteristic values for the various predictors used (you can choose the sort of person you're interested in), then apply `mvppred`. [author of `mvprobit`]

[You have a greater chance of getting help via Statalist Forum than here. I was directed here by someone, and don't/won't proactively look.]

Comment: Thank you very much! 

To get predicted binary values, should I do `mvppred xb` and set this to 1 if the value is positive and 0 otherwise?